# Plot a smooth and extrapolated curve using an nls model with several fitted parameters

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, nls

I feel that I am close to finding the answer for my problem, but somehow I just cannot manage to do it. I have used nls function to fit 3 parameters using a rather complicated function describing fertilization success of eggs (y-axis) in a range of sperm concentrations (x-axis) (Styan's model [[1]](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/286168), [[2]](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1558-5646.2008.00521.x/abstract)). Fitting the parameters works fine, but I cannot manage to plot a smoothed extrapolated curve using `predict` function (see at the end of this post). I guess it is because I have used a value that was not fitted on x-axis. My question is how to plot a smoothed and extrapolated curve based on a model fitted with `nls` function
using non-fitted parameter on x-axis?

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data.nls <- structure(list(S0 = c(0.23298, 2.32984, 23.2984, 232.98399, 2329.83993, 
23298.39926), fert = c(0.111111111111111, 0.386792452830189, 
0.158415841584158, 0.898648648648649, 0.616, 0.186440677966102
), speed = c(0.035161615379406, 0.035161615379406, 0.035161615379406, 
0.035161615379406, 0.035161615379406, 0.035161615379406), E0 = c(6.86219803476946, 
6.86219803476946, 6.86219803476946, 6.86219803476946, 6.86219803476946, 
7.05624476582978), tau = c(1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800, 1800
), B0 = c(0.000102758645352932, 0.000102758645352932, 0.000102758645352932, 
0.000102758645352932, 0.000102758645352932, 0.000102758645352932
)), .Names = c("S0", "fert", "speed", "E0", "tau", "B0"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

## Model S

modelS <- function(Fe, tb, Be) with (data.nls,{
x <- Fe*(S0/E0)*(1-exp(-B0*E0*tau))
b <- Fe*(S0/E0)*(1-exp(-B0*E0*tb))
x*exp(-x)+Be*(1-exp(-x)-(x*exp(-x)))*exp(-b)})

## Define starting values

start <- list(Fe = 0.2, tb = 0.1, Be = 0.1)

## Fit the model using nls

modelS.fitted <- nls(formula = fert ~ modelS(Fe, tb, Be), data = data.nls, start = start, 
control=nls.control(warnOnly=TRUE,minFactor=1e-5),trace = T, lower = c(0,0,0), 
upper = c(1, Inf, 1), algorithm = "port")

## Combine model parameters

model.data <- cbind(data.nls, data.frame(pred = predict(modelS.fitted)))

## Plot

ggplot(model.data) +
geom_point(aes(x = S0, y = fert), size = 2) +
geom_line(aes(x = S0, y = pred), lwd = 1.3) +
scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

I have tried following joran's example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918807/how-get-plot-from-nls-in-r), but it has no effect, maybe because I did not fit `S0`:

```
r <- range(model.data$S0)
S0.ext <- seq(r[1],r[2],length.out = 200)
predict(modelS.fitted, newdata = list(S0 = S0.ext))
# [1] 0.002871585 0.028289057 0.244399948 0.806316161 0.705116868 0.147974213
```

Comment: `modelS` has hard coded `data.nls` within it so prediction is unable to use anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You function should have the parameters `(S0,E0,B0,tau,Fe,tb,Be)`. `nls` will look for the parameters in the data.frame passed to its `data` argument and only try to fit those it doesn't find there (provided that starting values are given). No need for this funny `with` business in your function. (`with` shouldn't be used inside functions anyway. It's meant for interactive usage.) In `predict` `newdata` must contain all variables, that is S0,E0,B0, and tau.

Try this:

```
modelS <- function(S0,E0,B0,tau,Fe, tb, Be) {
  x <- Fe*(S0/E0)*(1-exp(-B0*E0*tau))
  b <- Fe*(S0/E0)*(1-exp(-B0*E0*tb))
  x*exp(-x)+Be*(1-exp(-x)-(x*exp(-x)))*exp(-b)}

## Define starting values

start <- list(Fe = 0.2, tb = 0.1, Be = 0.1)

## Fit the model using nls

modelS.fitted <- nls(formula = fert ~ modelS(S0,E0,B0,tau,Fe, tb, Be), data = data.nls, start = start, 
                     control=nls.control(warnOnly=TRUE,minFactor=1e-5),trace = T, lower = c(0,0,0), 
                     upper = c(1, Inf, 1), algorithm = "port")

## Combine model parameters

model.data <- data.frame(
  S0=seq(min(data.nls$S0),max(data.nls$S0),length.out=1e5),
  E0=seq(min(data.nls$E0),max(data.nls$E0),length.out=1e5),
  B0=seq(min(data.nls$B0),max(data.nls$B0),length.out=1e5),
  tau=seq(min(data.nls$tau),max(data.nls$tau),length.out=1e5))
model.data$pred <- predict(modelS.fitted,newdata=model.data)


## Plot

ggplot(data.nls) +
  geom_point(aes(x = S0, y = fert), size = 2) +
  geom_line(data=model.data,aes(x = S0, y = pred), lwd = 1.3) +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Obviously, this might not be what you want, since the function has multiple variables and more than one vary in `new.data`. Normally one would only vary one and keep the others constant for such a plot.

So this might be more appropriate:

```
  S0 <- seq(min(data.nls$S0),max(data.nls$S0),length.out=1e4)
  E0 <- seq(1,20,length.out=20)
  B0 <- unique(data.nls$B0)
  tau <- unique(data.nls$tau)

model.data <- expand.grid(S0,E0,B0,tau)
names(model.data) <- c("S0","E0","B0","tau")

model.data$pred <- predict(modelS.fitted,newdata=model.data)



## Plot

ggplot(model.data) +
  geom_line(data=,aes(x = S0, y = pred, color=interaction(E0,B0,tau)), lwd = 1.3) +
  geom_point(data=data.nls,aes(x = S0, y = fert), size = 2) +
  scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 @Roland especially for the last sentence about holding the other covariates constant.